# Need to modify style.css for a Joomla 3 Template

Tags: css, templates, stylesheet, joomla3.0

Be gentle - I am a css/template newbie!!

I'd like to modify the following style.css file to add space for a logo image to the left of the menu, space to the right of the menu for a search module, and a left sidebar to the left of the main content:

### #

```
<!--start of style.css file -->

body{line-height:1.7em;margin:0 auto;}
.main.pure-g-r,.splash .pure-g-r,.breadcrumbs.pure-g-r {letter-spacing: normal;}
.l-box{padding:1em;}
.pure-menu a.brand-link {display:inline}
.header{margin:0;}
.header .pure-menu{padding:.5em;}
.header .pure-menu li a:hover,.header .pure-menu li         a:focus{background:none;border:none;color:#aaa;}
body .primary-button{background:#02a6eb;color:#fff;}
.splash{background:#eee;margin:2em auto 0;padding:3em .5em;text-align: center;}
.splash .splash-head{font-size:300%;line-height:1.2em;margin:0;}
.splash .splash-subhead{color:#999;font-weight:300;line-height:1.4em;}
.splash .primary-button{font-size:150%;}
.content .content-subhead{color:#999;padding-bottom:.3em;text-    transform:uppercase;border-bottom:2px solid #eee;display:inline-block;margin:0;}
.content .content-ribbon{border-bottom:1px solid #eee;margin:3em;}
.ribbon{background:#eee;text-align:center;color:#999;padding:2em;}
.ribbon h2{display:inline;font-weight:400;}
.footer{background:#111;color:#aaa;text-align:center;font-size:80%;padding:1em;}

/*bootstrap stuff*/
.pull-left {
    float:left;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}

<!--end of style.css file -->
```

Can anyone help?  Extra "thank you" points for explaining how I can add/remove module elements to this style sheet.  Or am I working with the wrong file to modify this template?  BTW, this is from the JoomlaPure template.  Thanks!

Comment: Hello , give us HTML code that you want modify

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place specific modules in specific positions on your template this is don't through extensions > module manager. The module position needs to exist obviously (eg sidebar-a or search etc).

If the module position doesn't exist you will need to do a template override. This process differs between templates however there should be documentation on JoomlaPure - I coudn't find it after a quick search. The Joomla docs are here http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:How_to_use_the_Template_Manager#Creating_Overrides

Once you place the modules in the desired positions it's very easy to change the css in order to add padding or space between blocks as you say. Use DevTools / FireBug

Note also you should be using css overrides and not edit the core style.css - if you edit this file and you decide to update the template (to the latest version), you will lose your changes. Docs here http://www.joomla-monster.com/blog/customization/the-best-way-to-add-custom-css-styles-to-joomla-3-template

If this doesn't help, include a link to your website and I'll have a look.